# Is there a way to have number type parameters blank?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm creating a demographics report where users can choose what demographics they want to include on the report. One of the options is age range where the user can type in their own figures. Everything works except when the age range parameters are not used. The others can be blank as they are string types but the age range parameters are number types because I need to use them to do counting. Is there a way to use number type parameters but allow them to be blank if necessary?

I tried changing the type to string and then running a ToNumber formula to use the field for my needs but I get the same error. I also tried suppressing any fields that use number parameters but trying to say suppress is Not HasValue but that didn't work either.

Comment: What version are you using ? You should be able to set a default value when the user doesn't choose anything. Check this [link](https://answers.sap.com/questions/6119868/optional-parameter-in-crystal-report-xi-designer.html) about Crystal Reports XI.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!